# Deep Nested JSON Normalization in Python pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested-json

I want to convert deep nested JSON file into CSV. JSON file is

> {   "abcd-performance:output": {
> "performance": [
> {
> "sample": {
> "objectId": "abcd-device:100:12",
> "ifName": "Carrier1/1",
> "timeStamp": "2021-10-20T03:15:00.000Z",
> "type": "radio",
> "invalid": false,
> "attribute": [
> {
> "parameter": "rslReadingMean",
> "value": -36.4
> },
> {
> "parameter": "qam-32rx_time",
> "value": 0
> }
> ]
> }
> },
> {
> "sample": {
> "objectId": "abcd-device:100:12",
> "ifName": "Carrier1/1",
> "timeStamp": "2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z",
> "type": "radio",
> "invalid": false,
> "attribute": [
> {
> "parameter": "rslReadingMean",
> "value": -36.5
> },
> {
> "parameter": "qam-32rx_time",
> "value": 0
> }
> ]
> }
> },
> {
> "sample": {
> "objectId": "abcd-device:100:13",
> "ifName": "Terminal",
> "timeStamp": "2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z",
> "type": "sensor",
> "invalid": false,
> "attribute": [
> {
> "parameter": "InputCurrent",
> "value": 1.14
> },
> {
> "parameter": "Temperature",
> "value": 61.5
> },
> {
> "parameter": "InputVoltage",
> "value": 54.777
> }
> ]
> }
> }
> ]   } }

code

```
with open('Performance_Interface_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
df = pd.json_normalize(data['abcd-performance:output'], 'performance', max_level=4)
print(df.columns)
print(df)
```

Required output is
sample_objectId;sample_ifName;sample_timeStamp;sample_type;sample_invalid;sample_attribute_parameter;sample_attribute_value

i am not able to do the last column normalization.

Comment: Your `json` content and expected output is not readable. Please update the question in a way one can read the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specify the arguments to `meta` and `record_path` according to the JSON.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['abcd-performance:output']['performance'], record_path=['sample','attribute'], meta=[['sample', 'objectId'], ['sample', 'ifName'], ['sample', 'timeStamp'], ['sample', 'type'], ['sample', 'invalid']])

In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
        parameter   value     sample.objectId sample.ifName          sample.timeStamp sample.type sample.invalid
0  rslReadingMean -36.400  abcd-device:100:12    Carrier1/1  2021-10-20T03:15:00.000Z       radio          False
1   qam-32rx_time   0.000  abcd-device:100:12    Carrier1/1  2021-10-20T03:15:00.000Z       radio          False
2  rslReadingMean -36.500  abcd-device:100:12    Carrier1/1  2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z       radio          False
3   qam-32rx_time   0.000  abcd-device:100:12    Carrier1/1  2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z       radio          False
4    InputCurrent   1.140  abcd-device:100:13      Terminal  2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z      sensor          False
5     Temperature  61.500  abcd-device:100:13      Terminal  2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z      sensor          False
6    InputVoltage  54.777  abcd-device:100:13      Terminal  2021-10-20T03:30:00.000Z      sensor          False
```